# Overflow scroll in webview in iOS is not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, ios, web, dom

I am facing an issue with scroll in iOS in webview.
We have a div element for dropdown and another div element for the container. Container contains both input and dropdown div.

Can you pls explain what's the issue with this? I have attached the screenshot where the scrollbar is not aligned properly with the dropdown. How to set the top margin and bottom margin of the scrollbar with respect to choices?

```css
.acChoiceSetInputFilteredContainer {
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.acChoiceSetInputFilteredDropdown {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0.6px 1.8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1))
            drop-shadow(0px 3.2px 7.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13));
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100%);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```js
const choiceSetContainer = document.createElement("div");
choiceSetContainer.className = this.hostConfig.makeCssClassName(
    "ac-input",
    "ac-choiceSetInput-filtered-container"
);

this._textInput = document.createElement("input");
this._textInput.className = this.hostConfig.makeCssClassName(
    "ac-input",
    "ac-choiceSetInput-filtered-textbox"
);
this._textInput.type = "text";
this._dropdown = document.createElement("div");
this._dropdown.className = this.hostConfig.makeCssClassName(
    "ac-input",
    "ac-choiceSetInput-filtered-dropdown"
);

choiceSetContainer.append(this._textInput, this._dropdown);
```

Here is UX behaviour :
[image]

I tried adding few properties for scroll related to native scrolling but didn't work.